# Display custom price based on custom fields for Woocommerce simple product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In Woocommerce, I would like update base price depending on 2 selected custom fields.

With the help of LoicTheAztec I can update price of 1 custom field, so, how do a update 2 custom fields?

PHP code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_product_field' );
function custom_product_field() {
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) return; 
    $options = array(
    ""          => __('Tipos'),
    "20.00" => "Tipo 1 + 20,00",
    "25.00" => "Tipo 2 + 25,00",
    );
    woocommerce_form_field('amostra', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Tipos', $domain),
    'required'      => true,
    'options'       => $options,
    ),'');
    $options_ra = array(
    ""          => __('Sem Modelos'),
    "15.00" => "Modelo A + 15,00",
    "25.00" => "Modelo B + 25,00",
    );
    woocommerce_form_field('amostraB', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class_ra form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Modelos', $domain),
    'required'      => true,
    'options'       => $options_ra,
    ),'');
    $base_price = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
    $prices = array(
    ''      => wc_price($base_price),
    '20.00' => wc_price($base_price + 20),
    '25.00' => wc_price($base_price + 25),
    '15.00' => wc_price($base_price + 15),
    '25.00' => wc_price($base_price + 25),
    );
}
```

JS code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var a = <?php echo json_encode($prices); ?>,
        b = 'p.price',
        c = 'select[name="amostra"]';

    $(c).on( 'change', function(){
        $.each( a, function( key, value ){
            if( $(c).val() == key )
                $(b).html(value);
        });
    });
});
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krQux.jpg)

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code just handle the **displayed price** change on single product pages  based on custom fields selected values for simple products which price is not on sale.

This is a bit much more complicated as the 2 select fields can interact on the calculated price at the same time and of because this case, this need to be handled differently.

> The code **will not change the cart item price**, as more code is needed for that.

[image]

I have added some custom formatting price functions, to be able to achieve that… Here is the code:

```
// Custom formatting price function
function wc_custom_price( $price, $args = array() ) {
    $args = apply_filters( 'wc_price_args', wp_parse_args( $args, array(
        'ex_tax_label'       => false,
        'currency'           => '',
        'decimal_separator'  => wc_get_price_decimal_separator(),
        'thousand_separator' => wc_get_price_thousand_separator(),
        'decimals'           => wc_get_price_decimals(),
        'price_format'       => get_woocommerce_price_format(),
    ) ) );

    $unformatted_price = $price;
    $negative          = $price < 0;
    $price             = apply_filters( 'raw_woocommerce_price', floatval( $negative ? $price * -1 : $price ) );
    $price             = apply_filters( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', number_format( $price, $args['decimals'], $args['decimal_separator'], $args['thousand_separator'] ), $price, $args['decimals'], $args['decimal_separator'], $args['thousand_separator'] );

    if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', false ) && $args['decimals'] > 0 ) {
        $price = wc_trim_zeros( $price );
    }

    $formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $args['price_format'], '<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $args['currency'] ) . '</span>', '<span class="numeric-price">' . $price . '</span>' );
    $return          = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $formatted_price . '</span>';

    if ( $args['ex_tax_label'] && wc_tax_enabled() ) {
        $return .= ' <small class="woocommerce-Price-taxLabel tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
    }
    return apply_filters( 'wc_price', $return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price );
}

// Custom formated product price on single product pages for simple products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_get_price_html', 10, 2 );
function custom_get_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    if( '' === $product->get_price() || $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        return $price;
    } elseif ( is_product() && $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        $price = wc_custom_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    }
    return $price;
}

// Displaying selected custom fields calculated product price on single product pages for simple products
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'simple_product_price_custom_fields' );
function simple_product_price_custom_fields() {
    global $product;

    // Not for variable products and Not for products on sale
    if( ! $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_on_sale() )
        return;

    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    woocommerce_form_field('amostra', array(
        'type'     => 'select',
        'class'    => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'    => __('Tipos', $domain),
        'required' => true,
        'options'  => array(
            ''      => __('Sem Tipos', $domain),
            '20.00' => __('Tipo 1 + 20,00', $domain),
            '25.00' => __('Tipo 2 + 25,00', $domain),
        )
    ), '' );

    woocommerce_form_field('amostra_ra', array(
        'type'     => 'select',
        'class'    => array('my-field-class_ra form-row-wide'),
        'label'    => __('Modelos', $domain),
        'required' => true,
        'options'  => array(
            ''      => __('Sem Modelos', $domain),
            '15.00' => __('Modelo A + 15,00', $domain),
            '25.00' => __('Modelo B + 25,00', $domain),
        ),
    ), '' );

    $price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );

    $prices = array(
        ''      => $price,
        '20.00' => 20,
        '25.00' => 25,
        '15.00' => 15,
        '25.00' => 25,
    );

    // JS code ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var a  = <?php echo json_encode($prices); ?>,
            b  = 'p.price .numeric-price',
            f1 = 'select[name="amostra"]',
            f2 = 'select[name="amostra_ra"]',
            p  = <?php echo $price; ?>,
            p1 = 0, p2 = 0;

        $(f1).on( 'change', function(){
            $.each( a, function( key, value ){
                if( $(f1).val() == key ){
                    p1 = key == '' ? 0 : value;
                    $(b).html( parseFloat( p + p1 + p2 ).toFixed(2) );
                }
            });
        });

        $(f2).on( 'change', function(){
            $.each( a, function( key, value ){
                if( $(f2).val() == key ){
                    p2 = key == '' ? 0 : value;
                    $(b).html( parseFloat( p + p1 + p2 ).toFixed(2) );
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: its works perfectly for me, thank you for your help one more time  :)